# Spring, instance variable visibility in new thread started from @PostConstruct

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, visibility, postconstruct

Does spring garantee visibility of 'sleepInterval' and 'businessLogic' instance variables in case below?

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Service
public class SomeService implements Runnable {

  @Value("${sleepInterval}")
  private Long sleepInterval;

  @Autowired
  private BusinessLogicService businessLogic;

  @PostConstruct
  public void postConstruct() {
      new Thread(this).start();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
      while (true) {
          try {
              Thread.sleep(sleepInterval);

              businessLogic.doSomeBusinessLogic();

          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              //handle error
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I think there should be a visibility problem. But I couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: Why do you expect there'll be a problem? It is a method of a class accessing fields of same class..

Comment: @Vasan Actually I've expected potential NPE. Spring initialized all beans in a single thread, and autowired value (non-final and non-volatile) accessed from another thread. But NPE never happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won’t be a visibility problem. The Java Memory Model guarantees that everything done (or visible due to a happens-before relationship) in one thread before a call to Thread.start will be seen by the thread that was started:

From the specification in [the JLS section 17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.

Comment: found this part in spec. Thank you