# Do variables initialized in the @PostConstruct method need to be declared as volatile in Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, postconstruct

I do some initialization in Spring singleton bean @PostConstruct method (simplified code):

```java
@Component
public class Env {
    public String currentEnv;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        currentEnv = "dev";
    }
}
```

Should I worry about currentEnv visibility to other beans(other thread) and mark it volatile.

Answer (score 0):

No, I think it is not necessity.

Only one bean is responsible to initialize the variables and registered it in spring context. So the visibility is guaranteed.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html

Comment: ```one bean``` ? or are you referring to one thread

Comment: one bean and 1 thread, i don't see any document mention that spring use multiple threads to initialize variables ...

Comment: From the specification in the JLS section 17.4.5:A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.Because Spring beans are initialized in main thread,so other threads started in the main thread will see complete spring bean.Is this understanding correct?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49742762/spring-instance-variable-visibility-in-new-thread-started-from-postconstruct

Comment: yes, it's correct.

Answer (score -1):

By default, a Spring-managed Bean defined with `@Component` is a Singleton. This means that if you inject `Env` into another Spring-managed Bean and given that `currentEnv` is public, this other Bean could access it.

I would suggest making `currentEnv` private and creating a getter for the property instead:

```java
@Component
public class Env {
    private String currentEnv;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        currentEnv = "dev";
    }

    public String getCurrentEnv() {
        return currentEnv;
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean other bean can always see the latest "dev" value of currentEnv instead of the stale null when currentEnv not declared as volatile?@João Dias

Comment: Yes. But you should consider making `currentEnv` private and create a getter for the property instead.